# Haskell slice and lexing question

Tags: haskell

How are these two functions parsed?

```
>  (** (1/2)) $ 40
6.324555320336759
it :: Double

>  ((**) (1/2)) $ 40
9.094947017729282e-13
it :: Double
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one is a right section, and is shorthand for:

```
(\x -> x ** (1/2)) 40
```

The second one is using the function form of the operator `**`, essentially treating it as if it were a named function like `pow` or something:

```
(**) (1/2) 40
```

which equals

```
(1/2) ** 40
```

I've omitted the `$`s from your code because they are redundant.

```
(foo bar) $ baz = (foo bar) baz = foo bar baz
```

Comment: Depending on the fixity of `foo` the last one (`foo bar baz`) might not be equivalent to the other two.

Comment: @adamse, I meant for normal functions like `pow` or `(**)`.  But yeah the last one was a little out of place.  I just couldn't let `(foo bar) baz` be the last word, since those parens look awfully redundant :-)